# How do I concatenate a method call?

Tags: ruby

I am calling a method so:

```
Net::SSH.start( value, USER, :password => PASS, :keys => ["/keys/id_rsa"] ) do|ssh|
  mess = ssh.sudo "password", "apt-get upgrade"
end
```

The method is:

```
class Net::SSH::Connection::Session
  def sudo password, command            
    exec %Q%echo "#{password}" | sudo -S #{command}% do |channel, stream, data|
      stdout << data if stream == :stdout
    end
    return stdout
  end    
end
```

Later, I send an email with the mess variable and this works fine.

However, if I want to run through an array of hosts and try to append mess to a string like `results << mess`, all I get is an empty variable.  I don't know why this is.

Comment: Can you show how you iterate over the array of hosts? I'm suspecting scope, if results didn't exist before your loop, it gets created inside the loop and then when the loop exits it goes out of scope (i.e. disappears). As Matt says, you'd do well by defining it first, even if empty, so that it's available within the loop but doesn't go out of scope when the loop ends.

Comment: I use: hosts = {host1: '192.168.0.1', host2: '192.168.0.2', host3: '192.168.0.3'} and then: hosts.each do |key,value|

Comment: what I'm interested in is what you put inside the block (between `do |key, value|` and `end`) :)

Comment: Just this:Net::SSH.start( value, USER, :password => PASS, :keys => Net::SSH.start( value, USER, :password => PASS, :keys => ["/keys/id_rsa"] ) do|ssh|
    mess = ssh.sudo "password", "apt-get upgrade"
    update << mess
end

Comment: If I do not append, it does print the last message successfully.